# How to get the True Negative Rate from this code?

Tags: python, binary

I am in a larger code project and we have this one binary classifier. I want to calculate the TNR.

The major problem is that I don't find the information about the variables in the code.
What is the `benign rate`,  `guesses`  and `ad rate`,  `guesses`? And to calculate the TNR of that?
I am guessing that the TNR is `TNR = 2*benign_rate/len(y_hat)`.

```py
y_hat  = np.array([0, 1])
y_test = np.array([0, 1])

nr_not_detect_adv = 0
benign_rate = 0
benign_guesses = 0
ad_guesses = 0
ad_rate = 0
for i in range(len(y_hat)):
    if y_hat[i] == 0:
        benign_guesses += 1
        if y_test[i] == 0:
            benign_rate += 1
    else:
        ad_guesses += 1
        if y_test[i] == 1:
            ad_rate += 1

    if y_test[i] == 1:
        if y_hat[i] == 0:
            nr_not_detect_adv +=1

acc = (benign_rate+ad_rate)/len(y_hat)        
TP = 2*ad_rate/len(y_hat)
TNR = 2*benign_rate/len(y_hat)

precision = ad_rate/ad_guesses
recall = round(100*TPR, 2)
TPR = 2 * ad_rate / len(y_hat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `for` loop, I'd guess that meaning of the variables is:

- `y_hat`: predicted labels
- `y_test`: ground truth
- `beningn_rate`: TN (true negatives)
- `benign_guesses`: TN + FN (false negatives)
- `ad_rate`: TP (true positives)
- `ad_guesses`: TP + FP (false positives)
- `nr_not_detect_adv`: FN  (yes, it's redundant)

These lines should be fixed ([definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)):

```
TP = ad_rate
TNR = benign_rate/benign_guesses

precision = ad_rate/ad_guesses
recall = ad_rate / (ad_rate+nr_not_detect_adv)
TPR = recall
```